# Is there a way to use concepts to disable member functions that would produce a reference to void?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I would expect it to be possible to write a class like this

```cpp
template <class T>
struct A {
    T& operator*() 
        requires (!std::is_void_v<T>)
    {
        return *ptr;
    }
    T* ptr;
};
```

But if I write

```cpp
A<void> a;
```

I get the compiler error

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'struct A<void>':
prog.cc:16:13:   required from here
prog.cc:5:8: error: forming reference to void
    5 |     T& operator*()
      |        ^~~~~~~~
```

even though the requires clause disables that function.

Is there any way to write the class so that the disabled method is acceptable by the compiler?

(I'm aware I could partially specialize A for void but that's less convenient).

Comment: But why concept? For that is SFINAE.

Comment: By concepts, I  mean "concept features" (e.g. the requires clause). Is the question phrasing what's unclear to you?

Comment: @KamilCuk Because that's what concepts are for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is unfortunately not possible. I wish what you wrote actually worked, and it would be the correct way to write it if there was one, but you just can't do it.

Your options are:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct A {
    // #1: a type trait that handles void for you
    std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T> operator*() requires (!std::is_void_v<T>);

    // #2: make it a template (with only one valid instantiation)
    template <std::same_as<T> U=T>
        requires (!std::is_void_v<U>)
    U& operator*();

    // #3: use auto, even though we know the type and it's easy to spell
    auto& operator*() requires (!std::is_void_v<T>);
};
```

I dislike all three of them. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you have any idea from a language lawyer perspective why it's not possible? It's highly unintuitive why it doesn't work

Comment: Oh. Is this a thing where `T&` still needs to be valid even if the concept isn't satisfied because it's checking the validity of that portion _before_ it's checking to see if the member function is instantiated at all?

Comment: @RyanBurn Yeah once `T` isn't dependent, it just gets substituted everywhere way too eagerly.

Comment: Replacing T& with auto& also seems to work

Comment: @RyanBurn Yes, because we're no longer doing `T&`. But that's just differently bad.

Comment: I'm curious, what are the issues with #3? Why is using `auto&` like this a problem?

Comment: @cigien Because the return type is `T&`. Spelling that `auto&` is obfustication.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's fair; I was just worried there was something that could go wrong with using `auto&` here. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @cigien I suppose it could go wrong if you really did intent to return `T&` but then typoed and return some other lvalue there, which just happens to work, even though that's not the intent.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a pitfall whenever a deduced return type is used, which may be an argument against using it, but it doesn't make this particular usage any more unsafe.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was just asking why you think it's bad, and you explained it, and I then mentioned that I was relieved that there's nothing worse here than the usual pitfalls with deduced return types. I don't think we're disagreeing about anything.

Comment: Sadly trailing return type doesn't help either

Comment: I think using `decltype(auto)` might be a good alternative, something like `decltype(auto) operator*() requires (!std::is_void_v<T>)`

Comment: @康桓瑋 `decltype(auto)` is strictly worse than `auto&` - you're not only obfuscating the return type, but also the return value category.